# Ontonotes Treebanked Sentences Notation

Tags: nlp, text-processing

Here is an example of a sentence from [Ontonotes](http://www.bbn.com/ontonotes/)-[V3.0](http://www.ldc.upenn.edu/Catalog/docs/LDC2009T24/OntoNotes-Release-3.0.pdf). I wish to know the meaning of *T*-1 and *-2 in Treebanked sentence[ which I think is a tokenized version of the plain sentence]

### Plain sentence:

```
In the summer of 2005, a picture that people have long been looking forward to
started emerging with frequency in various major Hong Kong media.
```

### Treebanked sentence:

```
[Speaker#1] In the summer of 2005 , a picture that people have long been looking
forward to *T*-1 started *-2 emerging with frequency in various major Hong Kong
media .
```

There are also a few other tags like *PRO* and *PRO*-1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `*T*-1` thing represents a "trace" in the parse tree.  The reason you're seeing them is that OntoNotes builds on the Penn Treebank, which uses that annotation.

If you search the web for "penn treebank trace" you should find plenty to read about.  I found [this](http://www.ling.ohio-state.edu/~hinrichs/course07/ptb.pdf) document which has short explanation and examples for various `*X*` tags in the Penn Treebank, but there are probably more complete explanations out there.